# Running of curl processes in parallel in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl, json

I think post my data by curl command in terminal at the time but thousands of times to get a good turn. I wrote the following bash code:

```
  contents=$(< /Users/Andrea/Desktop/data.txt)
  eval "words=( $contents )”
  arguments=()
  for i in {1..10000}
  do
  arguments+=( "${words[@]}" );
  done;
  curl "${arguments[@]}”;
```

which my JSON data are saved in data.txt. When I execute the code it toke long time to post all request to the server and I do not get very good turn on the other hand many of this request post to the server after the time which is not useful. The data.txt include the following data

```
 --next 
 'https://d.server.com/easy/api/Order' 
 -H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
 -H 'Pragma: no-cache' 
 -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' 
 -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' 
 -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty'  
 -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
 Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36' 
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
 -H 'Origin: https://d.server.com' 
 -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' 
 -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' 
 -H 'Referer: https://d.server.com/' 
 -H 'Accept- Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8' 
 --data-binary '{"name":"Andrea","Id":13647,"family":Bianda,"pr":5400}' 
 -- compressed"
```

Now I was wondering how can I speed up the post of these curls and post many of them as possible one second before the time starts. The response of this curl is not important and in the case of of this get success the other request fails and my turn will show up.

Comment: You could run them in the background with `&` at the end. Still, it seems like a good way to get your IP (and probably your user) banned.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Could you please explain where I have to add `&` and why my IP will banned?

Comment: For the background processes you basically add an ampersand at the end of the command line. You might want to take a look at [this](https://linuxhandbook.com/run-process-background/). For the possible banning ... it's off topic. Forget I mentioned it.